# How to get recommendation for the user using 'linkedin' gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linkedin-api

I am able to get user information like user connections,education details, and work history.

is it possible to get recommendations for the logged in user using this

```
gem 'linkedin', :git => “git://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin.git"
```

Please provide me with example or the way to do the same.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev thanks for editing my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
recom = client.profile(:fields=>%w(recommendations-received))
recom.recommendations_received.all
```

More info can be found [Linkedin API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields#recommendations)

Comment: thanks for the post i will check and let you know the status. what is the need to use %w? could you please explain.

Comment: If there are more fields like with recommendation,education,position so it can fetch that field also by adding respective field name.

Comment: Thanks Amar, we got this really helpful. We are getting recommendations which are allowed by user, not all the recommendations. Can we get all (Allowed/Not allowed) recommendations with dates they have been published?